# What does :1 mean in dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

```
vsql='select ename into y from emp where empno=:1'
```

what does `:1` mean here?

Comment: Most likely a parameter placeholder. Depends on where this is written and in what language

Comment: See [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-4E5C6A4F-C1DB-44DD-964E-C683120B448E)

Comment: Your example code is incorrect. The assignment operator in PL/SQL is `:=` not `=` - are you sure this is for Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a ***placeholder*** for a parameter value you'll be using.

For example:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_empno number := 7902;
  3    v_sql   varchar2(200);
  4    l_ename varchar2(20);
  5  begin
  6    v_sql := 'select ename from emp where empno = :1';
  7    execute immediate v_sql into l_ename using l_empno;   --> this
  8    dbms_output.put_line(l_ename);
  9  end;
 10  /
FORD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```